# Source code for Apache flink force-shading dependency

Tags: maven, apache-flink

We need source code for the Flink shaded dependencies. As per the documentation on
https://github.com/apache/flink-shaded, sources are not released because of certain unanswered legal questions. However one can build the sources if required using

```
 mvn package -Dshade-sources
```

I am able to get the sources for all the other shaded dependencies except for the force-shading. Can someone please share if they are aware of getting source code for this particular dependency:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/force-shading/1.11.2

Answer (score 1):

The `force-shading` package doesn't have any sources (or dependencies). Since there's no code involved, no source JAR can be built for this package.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Could you please let me know the purpose of these shaded dependency. This jars are flagged by the open source clearance team.